# Seeking clarity regarding frame of reference in which robot velocities are provided

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, linear-velocity, frames

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a very simple doubt.

I have a robot with a body frame `B` attached very rigidly to it. I have a world frame `W` attached rigidly to the ground i.e. my inertial frame. When I publish a Twist message with some `linear` and `angular` velocity components, with respect to which frame are they published or considered?

From my knowledge, it is definitely not the world frame `W` because when I publish a positive in `linear.x` the robot just simply moves forward with respect to its instantaneous position. Is the answer something like with respect to the "instantaneous" body frame or something similar?

Seeking for clarity,

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395509/seeking-clarity-regarding-frame-of-reference-in-which-robot-velocities-are-provided/) by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2022-02-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-02-02**:
Just an observation: you seem to expect a generic answer, while in reality I believe it's very much possible for different `Twist` consumers to behave differently here. For some, the frame of reference may be the body-local frame, for others, an external one.

If you're observing behaviour of a specific component which made you ask this question, it would be good to mention that component, as it could help you getting (better) answers.

Note that the question would probably be different if you'd mentioned `TwistStamped`.

**Comment by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on 2022-02-02**:
Thank you for your response. To clarify my question. I had ground robots in my mind while asking this question. We can take the Turtlebot3 for example.

**Comment by [electrophod](https://answers.ros.org/users/43169/electrophod/) on 2022-02-02**:
Why would the question be completely different if I mentioned `TwistStamped` instead of `Twist`? I did not understand, please explain.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2022-02-03**:
@electrophod +1

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-02-03**:
See the second paragraph in @tryan's answer.

**Comment by [skpro19](https://answers.ros.org/users/36053/skpro19/) on 2022-02-03**:
@gvdhoorn that was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From what you describe, the short answer is that your `Twist` message is *probably* applied in the "'instantaneous' body frame" as you put it, but as @gvdhoorn mentioned, it's really up to the consumer to choose/assume the reference since there is no inherent frame in a simple [`Twist` message](http://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/Twist.html).  Velocities for a robot are commonly expressed in the [`base_link` frame](https://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0105.html#base-link), which is rigidly attached to the robot base, but it would be equally valid--and sometimes desirable--to express them in another frame.

If it's a [`TwistStamped` message](https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/TwistStamped.html) instead, it has a [`header` component](https://docs.ros.org/en/noetic/api/std_msgs/html/msg/Header.html), which includes a timestamp and a frame of reference.  Then, the answer is more concrete since the supplied velocities are explicitly attached to a specific frame at a specific time.  If you want someone to comment on what's happening in your case for certain, please provide more context.

---

Originally posted by [tryan](https://answers.ros.org/users/33908/tryan/) with karma: 1421 on 2022-02-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2